# Nodejs creating image from chunks on data

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, mjpeg, chunks

How can I extract the relevant data and store as image. I want to extract the chunks to store them as images. How can I do that?

```
Content-type:image/jpeg
Content-Length:28178
ÿØÿà JFIF   ÿÛ Å (#(#!#-+(0<dA<77<{X]Id‘€™–€ŒŠ ´æÃ ªÚ­ŠŒÈÿËÚîõÿÿÿ›Áÿÿÿúÿ
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just pipe the streams together, like:

```
request('url/stream').pipe(f);
```

Also, it looks like the response is a multipart document (judging by the line that starts with two dashes). Assuming this is the case, you can use a module such as [`dicer`](https://github.com/mscdex/dicer) to parse it.

Comment: Yes it is, but I just want to save the images. How can I do that?

Comment: When you pipe the response to `dicer`, you can stream the part that contains the image (you can check that the part's `Content-Type` header contains `image/jpeg`) to your `fs.WriteStream`.